# Python - find and replace - copy result to clipboard in Automator

Tags: python, service, automator

I have a python script working perfectly when executed from terminal. But when trying to go through automator i just get "Run Shell Script" error.

*Goal: (mind you, complete noob here, hence the 'noob' task)  In my day job (different discipline) im always collaborating with people on windows and mac alike.  Im on a mac, so trying to make a quick right click drop down service to retrieve the files path > find /, replace with \ and also the difference in beginning of server path > copy to clipboard.  This way giving someone a windows version of the path is a click and paste away. scripting 101 im sure.*

Its all great on my .py doc through terminal...obviously give's me the path of my doc, looking great so far.  To mobilize this thing i heard Automator is a great way to do so.

I get the specified error when set up: **Run Shell Script** Shell: /usr/bin/python  Pass Input: as arguments.  Code:

```
import os

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

userlink = os.path.realpath(__file__)

reps = {'/':'\\','///':'\\', 'rr1mgsfile46':'gameshare\\share\\IEBDesign','smb:':''}

txt = replace_all(userlink, reps)


cmd = 'echo %r | tr -d "\n" | pbcopy' % txt
os.system(cmd)
```

Ive also simply tried using Shell: /bin/bash and directing it to the .py with the same result.  There's a lot of guess work here so i can only imagine all of the way this is wrong.  But, it does work in terminal, so i feel i cant be too far off.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing to be aware of with Python scripting is which version of Python that you are using.  Pyton 2 and python 3 have a great number of incompatibilities.  My version of OS X, Mountain Lion, uses Python 2.7.2, but I had 3.3.1 running from the command-line.   This can be an issue.  http://ideone.com/iaKiTE

Comment: This might be in some cases an issue. The example does not run in 3.3. But I think the problem was more an automator thing. I suggest changing the python tag to python2.7.

Comment: i actually suspected that and was sort of hoping posting this would give me a straight confirmation thats the case.(the v3 vs v2.7) i am however, using 2.7 with Mountain Lion's Automator. Will give the tag change a try

Comment: ...if i can figure out how to change the tag, the UI just provides a dropdown menu to python.  Which still baffles me.  If running 'python'+script in terminal works...why would running /usr/bin/python+ script in what seems to be a pseudo (run shell script) terminal not?

Comment: @EricSanderson: As pointed out below, the os.path.realpath(__file__) does not work in Automator.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into detail, this worked for me on Snow Leopard. You can test it, if you put a Finder 'Ask for Finder Item' Dialogue in front.

```
import sys
import os

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

for userlink in sys.argv[1:]:
    # print('pbcopy ' + userlink) # this is for testing
    os.system('pbcopy ' + f)
    reps = {'/':'\\','///':'\\', 'rr1mgsfile46':'gameshare\\share\\IEBDesign','smb:':''}
    txt = replace_all(userlink, reps)

    cmd = 'echo %r | tr -d "\n" | pbcopy' % txt
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: thanks.  Im still getting the error, but im running OSX 10.8 which i think is Mountain Lion.  Knowing that works in Snow Leopard, maybe i can use that as a control to figure out the idiosyncrasies between the two.  Unless someone else has a known working bit of code for osx 10.8.

Comment: update:  Found the script actually 'runs' fine in Automator with no problem.  Its when clicking on a file and actually trying put it in action is when i get the error.

Comment: I wonder why there is a difference between your Automator action and clicking on a file. :-/ For me this works fine. Thank you for the idea to use Automator in such a way! ;-)

Comment: @EricSanderson: What script did you mean in the edit of my answer above? Your version or mine. I found that your version did not work for me because of os.path.real(__file__). The structure of the Automator input seems different.

Comment: My first act in here was copying your code into automator, so all subsequent comments have been based on the provided code.  Which as stated, Automator seems to not have a problem with intrinsically.  But gives me an error right clicking and trying to execute from a file.  This may be of significance or not: Pass Input: as arguments give me "run shell script" encountered an error.  Pass Input as "to stdin", provides no error, false hope though as nothing is pasted to the clipboard.  Snow Leopard seems to be our difference i guess.

Comment: about to give up.  All my research seems to suggest the default env automator uses for python doesnt afford, or isnt consistent with what shell accesses/provides, as far as i can interpret anyway.  Ive run just about every work around people supply for such issues to no differing results. Seem to have run the internet dry on the subject at this point.

Comment: @EricSanderson: :-/ others will have the same problem in the future. When I have ended some work I want to finish on this operating system I will try again. Another option is to ask the apple people... ;-)

Comment: already have a post in their discussion board :)  No bites yet. Seems to be a common problem, though.  With a wide array of hack type solutions from what i can see.

Comment: [example 1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4944256?start=0&tstart=0)

[example 2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2371214?start=0&tstart=0)

these are a couple i could retrieve at the moment.  Other solutions suggested shbangs #! directly to python, etc.

Comment: may be a face palm moment but i got it to work.  As someone pointed out in the apple discussion board.  f wasnt defined anywhere ('pbcopy ' + f).  deleting it gave me the result i needed.  Kind of hard to bug test a script when automator gives you the thumbs up with an error in the code.